# Error in Integrate Google Adwords conversion code in Contact Form 7 Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, google-ads-api, contact-form-7

I want to integrate Google conversion code in Contact form 7 Plugin. I have setup everything.
but getting error when form submits.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined

```
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (scripts.js?ver=4.8:256), <anonymous>:1:1)
at String.<anonymous> (scripts.js?ver=4.8:256)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at ajaxSuccess (scripts.js?ver=4.8:256)
at Object.<anonymous> (scripts.js?ver=4.8:324)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at A (jquery.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Contact form 7 A Additional Settings are as below

[image: contact form 7 Additional Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace Additional Settings with `on_sent_ok: "typeof goog_report_conversion === 'function' && goog_report_conversion();"`

and Put Google Adword Conversion code at the bottom of form as it is.

Answer (score 0):

`on_sent_ok` and `on_submit` are deprecated and scheduled to be abolished by the end of 2017.

You can use `DOM`-events instead of these settings.

You can use this function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
var img = document.createElement("img");
var goalId = "868xxxxxx"; // Your Google Conversion ID
var randomNum = new Date().getMilliseconds();
var value = 0;
var label = "WoZxxxxxxxxxx"; // Your Google Conversion Label
var url = encodeURI(location.href);
var trackUrl = "http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/"+goalId+"/?random="+randomNum+"&value="+value+"&label="+label+"&guid=ON&script=0&url="+url;
img.src = trackUrl;
document.body.appendChild(img);
}, false ); 
</script>
```